# how to set an active listen function that wait and listens for a command from user

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, artificial-intelligence

I was working on this javascript program that listens to the users command and replies correspondingly but currently, that listen() function is activated by a click of a button. What I'm trying to figure out is how can I set a function that constantly keeps listening for a command from the user like a certain word that then activates the listen() function. Ex. Alexa starts listening when her name is called.
Current Code:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored" onclick="listen()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having another onInput listener which will check whether a user has entered a certain word.

Once that word is entered then invoke a function to add a listen() event listener to that button.

eg:
HTML -

```
<input type="text" name="" id="userI">
<button id="activate">Find Secret</button>
```

JS -

```
const btn = document.getElementById("activate");
const input = document.getElementById("userI");


input.addEventListener("input", (e) =>{
    if(input.value=="secret")
    {
        btn.addEventListener("click", secret);
    }
})

const secret = () => {
    alert("Secret is....");
}
```

This is just an idea. You can add many improvements. Like removing the event listener again. And so on.